# how to click on javascript element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<a href="javascript:onclick=valueIs='low';loadData('low')" id="tab8" class="sel">52 Low</a>
```

This is how the html part is coded by developer

Comment: I tries this, but it does not works:
     ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('52 Low').click()");

Comment: Why do you want to click it with JavascriptExecutor when u can do it by `driver.findElement(By.id('tab8')).click();` .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the ID of the link (tab) is not changing then you should put:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('tab8').click()");
```

or even simplier (as Vivek noted):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).findElement(By.id('tab8')).click();
```

In case the ID of the tab could potentially change you could search it by its text:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "var tabs= document.getElementsByTagName("a");" +
    "var tabText= "52 Low";" +
    "for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {" +
    "  if (tabs[i].textContent == tabText) {" +
    "    tabs[i].click();" +
    "    break;" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
```